# Handling invalid records in fact table after MERGE statement

Tags: sql, database, etl, data-modeling, scd

How do I best handle invalid records in a fact table after a MERGE statement?

This is my fact table: `schema_name.fact_table`

This is my dimensional table (SCD2): `schema_name.dim_table`

In my `dim_table` I have a proper SCD2 with unique surrogate keys and the table as a whole is in 1NF. Now, when a change occurs in my SCD2 table, business key stays the same, old row is invalidated and marked as `IS_CURRENT = 0` and a new row is added with new values, different surrogate key and same business key.

Moving on to fact table:
`1. TRUNCATE TABLE stage.stage_fact` 
`2. INSERT INTO stage.stage_fact` 
`3. MERGE INTO schema_name.fact_table USING stage.stage_fact`

Now, you can probably see what is happening - if a change in SCD2 occurs, I will be inserting a new row and no change will happen on now invalid row. In the end, I will end up with a duplicated row in fact table which is a big no-no.

For now I am handling this as I am simply running a DELETE statement (could replace with UPDATE), but this seems more like a hack and not a proper way to do things.

Is there any better way to do things?

Comment: what about a after INSERT trigger that first check if the data is already the sets the row to 0 and then insert and that row for row. bulk insert can be faster, but to have te data straight, it will be a better way

Comment: Hi - can you explain why a change in scd causes duplicate rows in your fact table? Your Dim and Fact tables are independant - why would your Dim being SCD2 affect the number of rows you load into your Fact table?